# Slick Slider Not Working - Arrows and Dots or Carousel Not Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, slick.js

I have tried to get the Slick Slider to work, but whatever I do the arrows and dots does not appear, or the carousel. I have looked at the other threads and none answers my question. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to follow the configurations from the Slide website and watching videos on Youtube.

This is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zqcrbytv/1/

HTML:

```html
<section class="center slider">
  <div><img src="Pictures/Captain_Marvel_poster.cropped.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="Pictures/venom.cropped.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="Pictures/Captain_Marvel_poster.cropped.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="Pictures/venom.cropped.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="Pictures/Captain_Marvel_poster.cropped.jpg"></div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/slick/slick.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/slick/slick.js" defer></script>
```

Best regards,
Danielle

Answer (score 0):

Could you update your Fiddle with complete paths so that we can actually test your code?

Thx

Comment: I am not 100% how to do that. Is there something missing? 
Here is the website: http://www.student.city.ac.uk/~aczc972. The Carousel is supposed to be shown under 'Movies'. You can see it when inspecting the code.

Comment: The only thing I see is that you have 5 slides and you set the slidesToShow to 5, so arrows and dots are not shown (they're used for navigation and there's no navigation to do in this case). Try setting slidesToShow and slidesToScroll to 1 and see if dots and arrows appear.

Comment: Nothing happens. I only chose slick because it was said to be an easily implemented carousel, although I do not get it to work. Do I need to reference the latest javascript version in my body?

Comment: Yes! Of some reason, it impacts my whole website, including making my main slideshow super big so it is impossible to use the website.

Thanks for helping me! This is driving me mad!